# Am I alone or others too find "Close>Duplicate>Search" Slow or Irrelevant

Tags: discussion

**1. Questions that may already have your answer**

**2. Close>Duplicate>Search**

These are the places where StackOverflow shows up with relevant Questions. I find it totally useless. I am showing two images here,

[image]

[image]

You can see the top result of both searches, StackOverflow results are no where near the written keywords and Google is bang on.!!

I am pointing this not to find negatives of the StackOverflow, b*ut to take count of duplicate question down by showing them exact already asked and answered question while writing the title*.

So, My question is, on what basis it searches Tags or Simple Keywords, does it compare to Title <> Title or Title <> Description ?

Comment: This has been complained about many times, but I can't find the duplicate.  (Seriously though, there are occasional requests to improve this (or replace it with a list of favorite dup targets or simply the most targeted questions in the tags) but nothing's been done yet.)

Comment: Sorry.! I tried to search while creating this Question but had no any similar question shown. Irony.

Comment: If nothings gonna happen, should I delete this one to make Internet Less Polluted and support Single reference Q/A policy. :)

Comment: You can try out the self-close-as-dupe feature first if you want.

Comment: Did that, Feeling awesome.! :D

Comment: Hurray. It is 2018 by now, and nothing changed!